# how to convert expression to string in z3

Tags: expression, tostring, z3

There are two expr_vector A,B, I am trying to compare the elements in them using

```
if(strcmp(A[i].ToString(),B[i].ToString()) == 1)
```

And the error ‘class z3::expr’ has no member named ‘ToString’,which is found on [override string ToString   (       )](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_expr.html#aa73e7c4dd1df5fd5fbf81c7764ee1533)   .

Or could you please tell me how to compare the variables in the two expr_vector? Such as the variable q1 is in the vector`<expr>`A and B respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided in your question is for the Z3 C# (.Net) API, and your question suggests you are using the C++ API (`expr_vector` is a class of the Z3 C++ API).

To test whether `a` and `b` are equal, where `a` and `b` are `z3::expr`, we should use `eq(a, b)`.
The `eq` function is just a wrapper for `Z3_is_eq_ast`, and is defined at `z3++.h`

```
friend bool eq(ast const & a, ast const & b) { return Z3_is_eq_ast(a.ctx(), a, b) != 0; }
```